# How much current can AS6C6416 static RAM data pins source?

Tags: current-source, pins

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNT55y5eKwI&t=9s) where the presenter uses static RAM data pins to source current to LEDs.

I want to try this, but I have [AS6C6416](https://www.alliancememory.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/Alliance%20Memory_64M_AS6C6416-55TIN%20v1.0%20July%202017.pdf) chip. My question is – will this not damage the chip? I checked the datasheet but couldn’t find the maximal current each pin of this RAM can source.

Comment: Please summarize the portion of the video that is relevant so that people don't have to watch/skim an 18-minute video to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet shows 50 mA for **DC Output Current** under **Absolute Maximum Ratings** on page 4. This is likely *total*, not per pin. Use appropriate current-limiting resistors such that with all LEDs driven the total current is below this value.

[image: AS6C6416 Datasheet excerpt, absolute maximum ratings]

Comment: I looked into using a 74HC244 buffer. Its datasheet states that output current Io is 35 mA (Nexperia datasheet, table 4 on page 4) - is it per each pin or total for eight output pins? Thank you.

Comment: Unless explicitly stated, the output current will be for the whole package, not per pin.